# Jackrabbit Observation with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jackrabbit

I am new to observation, although the repository supports observation, 
onEvent() is never invocked. Here're the details:

I created a **Param** class, and it's just a POJO with setters and getters 
hasing properties that each represents a parameter for: 
**ObservationManager.addEventListener()**

I careted an interface **XListener** that extends **EventListener**, and defined a 
method: **Params getParameters()**.

Crated **MyEventListener** implements **XListener** and implements the 
getParameters() and onEvent()
getParameters() just populate a Param object (with NODE_ADDED) and return 
it to be used later to add **this** listener,
and onEvent() currently it only prints out a message **NEW NODE ADDED**.

Then created a new class **ListenerRigistrar** and added it in the 
applicationContext.xml for Spring with a  which is a set 
of XListeners.
Added a new bean for MyEventListener.

back to ListenerRegistrar, I iterate over the set of listeners and use the 
Params object embeded with the listener to call 
ObservationManager.addEventListener()

The problem is that the message NEW NODE ADDED is never printed means 
onEvent() method is never invocked!!

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem you have is that your ListenerRegister is never being invoked (looks like it's simply declared it in the application context).

As you're using Spring and JCR, I suggest you use [Spring Modules](https://springmodules.dev.java.net), and follow [these](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/docs/reference/0.8/html_single/#d0e5257) instructions.

Good luck,

--dj